# Entity Framework 4.1 & existing database

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

Hi I have an existing database with a table with 30 fields, I want to split the table into many models so I could retrieve/save fields that I need and not every time retrieve/save the whole object from the db. using c#.

I think I should be using Code-First. Could someone provide an example or a tutorial link?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to split table to be able to load a subset of field or persist subset of fields. Both operations are available with the whole table mapped to single entity as well.

For selection you simply have to use projection:

```
var data = from x in context.HugeEntities
           select new { x.Id, x.Name };
```

You can use either anonymous type in projection or any non-mapped class.

For updates you can simply use:

```
var data = new HugeEntity { Id = existingId, Name = newName };
context.HugeEntities.Attach(data);
var dataEntry = context.Entry(data);
dataEntry.Property(d => d.Name).IsModified = true; // Only this property will be updated
context.SaveChanges();
```

Or:

```
var data = new HugeEntity { Id = existingId };
context.HugeEntities.Attach(data);
data.Name = newName; 
context.SaveChanges(); // Now EF detected change of Name property and updated it
```

Mapping multiple entities to single table must follows very strict rules and it is possible only with table splitting were all entities must be related with one-to-one relation (and there are some problems with more than two entities per split table in code first) or with table-per-hierarchy inheritance. I don't think that you want to use any of them for this case.